Gnome session restarts automatically when screen is off
I have the following mysterious behavior: When I turn off my screen on the PC with the on/off button on the screen, wait a few minutes and turn the screen back on, the Gnome session restarts. This is not just the “screen locked” state. All programs are closed and Gnome restarts when I enter my credentials.
What is wrong with my Gnome?
(Ubuntu 24.04 Gnome)

How do you "turn off my screen"? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

With the on/off Button on my screen

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
